# Azure virtual network - How to change localnetworksite address space?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I need to change the address space prefix in my virtual network configuration. How can I do this?

```
<LocalNetworkSites>
<LocalNetworkSite name="xxx-xxx-DC">
<AddressSpace>
<AddressPrefix>xx.xx.15.0/24</AddressPrefix>
<AddressPrefix>xx.xx.67.0/24</AddressPrefix>
</AddressSpace>
<VPNGatewayAddress>xx.xxx.xx.xx</VPNGatewayAddress>
</LocalNetworkSite>
</LocalNetworkSites>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your extract shows the local network definition whilst your question seem to refer to the virtual network itself, but actually it doesn't really matter as the answer is the same - You can't change the address space for either on a created network.

You will have to

1. Export the configuration
2. Make the changes you require (make sure to change subnets as well)
3. Delete the network
4. Re-create the network by importing the modified configuration
5. Re-deploy your services

Comment: I have 3 vm's that are stood up plus the vpn tunnel, will all this need to be recreated from scratch?

Comment: You will have to delete the VMs, yes, but you don't have to delete the disks, so re-creating the VMs would be fairly straight forward over the existing disks. The network definition, including the local network will remain in the exported configuration, so you will only have to re-deploy the gateway

Answer (score 0):

Yossi,
Is this a Microsoft supported solution?. The reason I ask is apart from having to create the vm's I also have to change the config on the local vpn side as the IP address of the gateway and shared key changes. Fortunately I only have 3 vm's but lets say I had 20, this would not be a sustainable solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user3120398 that this is not a viable and sustainable solution and it still seems to be modus operandi more than a year later :-(